# Batch Alternate Data Streams

Tags: file, batch-file

I am almost done with my game and have employed "Alternate Data Streams" to save some high scores in a ADS.  Now i tried to do the same with a color option, to make the game be the same color scheme you set it every time you open it until you want to change it.  Here is the code that i am working on:

```
echo.
echo Color Options - background/text
echo ------------------
echo 0) Black
echo 1) Blue
echo 2) green
echo 3) Aqua
echo 4) Red
echo 5) Purple
echo 6) Yellow
echo 7) White
echo 8) Grey
echo ------------------
set /p BcolorSetting=Background:
set /p TcolorSetting=Text:
echo %BcolorSetting%%TcolorSetting% >>"%~f0:colors"
color <"%~f0:colors"
pause
```

If you want to see the whole thing it's...

```
@echo off
REM Produced by Calder Hutchins
REM This is a game
title Memory Game
:begin
set point=0
cls
echo.
echo Memeory Game
echo ------------------
echo 1) Play
echo 2) Instructions
echo 3) High Scores
echo 4) Options
echo ------------------
set /p pick=^>
if %pick%==1 goto one
if %pick%==2 goto two
if %pick%==3 goto three
if %pick%==4 goto four 
if %pick%==99 goto test 
goto begin
:one
cls
REM Determines the number
if %point% LSS 6  set /a rand=%random% %% (100 - 1 + 1)+ 1
if %point% LSS 12 if %point% GTR 5 set /a rand=%random% %% (500 - 100 + 1)+ 100
if %point% LSS 18 if %point% GTR 11 set /a rand=%random% %% (1000 - 500 + 1)+ 500
if %point% LSS 24 if %point% GTR 17 set /a rand=%random% %% (2000 - 1000 + 1)+ 1000
if %point% LSS 30 if %point% GTR 23 set /a rand=%random% %% (9000 - 1500 + 1)+ 1500
if %point% LSS 36 if %point% GTR 29 set /a rand=%random% %% (19000 - 5000 + 1)+ 5000
if %point% LSS 42 if %point% GTR 35 set /a rand=%random% %% (32000 - 10000 + 1)+ 10000
if %point% LSS 48 if %point% GTR 41 set /a rand=%random% %% (999 - 100 + 1)+ 100
if %point% LSS 48 if %point% GTR 41 set /a randtwo=%random% %% (999 - 100 + 1)+ 100
if %point% GTR 47 set /a rand=%random% %% (9999 - 1000 + 1)+ 1000
if %point% GTR 47 set /a randtwo=%random% %% (9999 - 1000 + 1)+ 1000
echo.
REM  Prints the number  
if %point% LSS 42 echo %rand% 
if %point% GTR 41 set rand=%rand%%randtwo%
if %point% GTR 41 echo %rand%
echo.
ping localhost -n 3 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
set /p yourOption=Guess:
REM Determines correct or wrong
if %youroption%==%rand% set /a point=%point% +1 & goto one
cls
echo.
echo You scored: %point%
echo.
set /p name=Type name:
echo %name%  -  %point% >>"%~f0:scores"
goto begin
:two
cls
echo. 
echo The objective of the game is to get as many points as possible.  To get points you must correctly retype the numbers that appear on the screen.  The numbers show for a short period of time.  As you get more points the numbers get longer!  When you have lost you will be prompted to enter your name.  You can view the highscores too!  
echo. 
pause
goto begin
:three
cls
echo.
more<"%~f0:scores" | sort
echo.
pause
goto begin
:four
cls
echo.
echo Settings/Options
echo ------------------
echo 1) color
echo ------------------
set /p pickSetting=^>
if %pickSetting%==1 goto oneSetting
goto four
:oneSetting
cls
echo.
echo Color Options - background/text
echo ------------------
echo 0) Black
echo 1) Blue
echo 2) green
echo 3) Aqua
echo 4) Red
echo 5) Purple
echo 6) Yellow
echo 7) White
echo 8) Grey
echo ------------------
set /p BcolorSetting=Background:
set /p TcolorSetting=Text:
echo %BcolorSetting%%TcolorSetting% >>"%~f0:colors"
color <"%~f0:colors"
pause
goto begin
```

Thank-you in advance guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately the `FOR /F` can read ADS:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%C in ("%~f0:colors") do COLOR %%C
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you will have to CD a certain directory. Then, write to a text file within the  directory. In the start, read the text file.
Then, overwrite the text file and write the color in it at the point you are stuck in.

If you need to start with settings in any app, you always need a save file.
Writing can be like this:

```
echo %BcolorSetting%%TcolorSetting% >>"colorsetting.txt"
```

And when retrieving, do it in the very beginning. Before begin.
It is read like this

```
set /p %~f0:colors= <colorsetting.txt
```

Assuming you use those variables. I hope this helps.